# NHibernate mapping for SQL Server 2008 Hierarchy Data Type

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-2008

Just wondering what the best mapping pattern is for NHibernate (latest release) with SQL Server 2008 and the hierarchy data type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with this new type in Sql Server 2008 but I suspect you will need to create (or find) a [custom type](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx) if you want to take full advantage of it in object terms